# Localhost server in loopback does not answer incoming SYN

Tags: interface, ip, wireshark, loopback, winpcap

I have a TCP server which runs in localhost (127.0.0.1), I am trying to connect to the server by injecting SYN packets to the loopback interface, but the server doesn't answer them.  These packets have the source IP of the Ethernet interface of my internet adapter (and not localhost IP).

I watch the SYN packet that goes to my loopback server in Wireshark, but the server does not answer it with a SYN/ACK.  I think it is because the IP source is not 127.0.0.1, which for example is 192.168.1.24.

If I go to the browser and I connect to my localhost server it works fine, but the source IP that I am using is 127.0.0.1 and the destination IP is 127.0.0.1 too; the only difference between the packets is the source IP.

I want to establish a TCP connection with my loopback server (localhost) by using different IP source addresses than 127.0.0.1.  Is that possible?

For example, a Loopback TCP SYN packet which comes from 192.168.1.24 to 127.0.0.1 should be answered by the loopbackserver?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can send packets to localhost via `Npcap Loopback Adapter` and get response from the counterpart (e.g. a process on the same machine). An example is Nmap, Nmap uses `Npcap Loopback Adapter` to scan the ports of localhost. The command is: `nmap -v -A 127.0.0.1`. Nmap is open-sourced [here](https://github.com/nmap/nmap), so you can see its code about the implementation. If you think Nmap is too complicated, you can see the source code of Nping [here](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/tree/master/nping), a ping tool shipped by Nmap. Nping also uses `Npcap Loopback Adapter` when pinging localhost, which works differently with the original ping shipped by Windows.

Using IP of one of local adapters or using 127.0.0.1 should be the same. You can run Nmap to test it. Whatever, using 127.0.0.1 is the best and recommended by Npcap when talking to localhost.

So I think the issue still relates to your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server [`bind()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) using `INADDR_LOOPBACK`?  If so, you could try changing it to `INADDR_ANY` to see if that helps.  See also [man 7 ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html).

(These links are obviously Linux-specific; if your platform is something else, then refer to the documentation applicable to your system.  For example, if you're on Windows, then maybe refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550(v=vs.85).aspx.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, thank you very much for your answers.

The problem was a bit stupid, I was trying to establish a TCP connection with the loopback server (localhost) with IP source addresses that were not in the range of the loopback, loopback gateway: 127.0.0.1, loopback netmask: 255.255.0.0; It cant accept packets from IP source addresses that are not in the range of 127.0.X.X ; if I do NAT and I translate the packet from for example 192.168.1.154 to 127.0.1.154 the packet is received by the server and I can establish the server connection, I do not know how I did not realize it before.

Thank you for the time, regards!.

I think too that maybe it is better to bind the server to other virtual network adapter and not to the loopback, I am studing this: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/ndis/netvmini/6x

It would be fine to create a miniport driver and bind the server there, we would have the advantage of having our own gateway and netmask and the layer would be ethernet and not BSD loopback. Your opinions will be interesting for me.